# The best ux alternative in designing variant of a product on dashboard

Tags: website-design, user-research, dashboard, point-of-sale, user-behaviour

I was wondering what would be the best way to display variant when a user clicks on "Add Variant". I already designed two alternatives: display it in ascending order or descending order. I have tested it to internal stakeholders but I still hesitate because the results are 50:50, either they chose Alternative-A or Alternative-B.

On Alternative A, when a user clicks "add variant" then it will appear in ascending order. After the user filled the product variant name, the variant 1 will be automatically changed based on the product variant name, so on. The latest variant will be placed on the bottom. Example:

variant 1

variant 2

variant 3 [this is the latest]

**Alternative A:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

On Alternative B, when a user clicks "add variant" then it will appear in descending order. After the user filled the product variant name, the variant 1 will be automatically changed based on the product variant name, so on. But, the latest variant will be placed on top. Example:

variant 3 [this is the latest]

variant 2

variant 1

**Alternative B:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

I would be glad if someone could give me an opinion and a strong justification to which best UX alternative from those two options. On the other hand, I would like to put an indicator state to the latest variant but I still have no idea how to present it. Maybe you could offer me an idea regarding the indicator state.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How many variants can be added?

Comment: @rhauger I assume that the number of variants wouldn't be more than 10 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to place the button underneath the list of variants and add the variants downwards. For indication i placed a small label on the new variant to make it easy to differentiate but keep the list scan-able. I also placed a "delete"-icon on the variant because the user might want to remove an variant, you could also add an "edit" or "move"-icon to make it even easier to handle the list.
I think this way it's clear where i add what and how.

[image]

Comment: Hi Rhauger, thanks for your suggestion! Structurally it looks systematic and clear. In this case, you prefer the ascending order, right? Perhaps you have an explanation why do you prefer the ascending instead of descending order?

Comment: Yes, ascending. In my example the "add"-button is at the end of the list, this is the place where you add an element to the list that's why the element should appear at the end. In the analog world you would also add things to a list in ascending order. A nice animation would also enhance UX (for example, fade in / slide in the new element after creation). This would also bring more focus on the new element.

Comment: It's about what the user expects to happen.

Comment: Alright, based on your design and justification, it makes sense! Thanks a lot, Rhauger!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two concepts mixed:

- The logic of interactivity
- The logic of the operation

The logical position of a sum operation is this:

[image]

When adding a new operation, the symbol of the operation is placed next to the last result already obtained. This in interactivity would translate as:

[image]

There's a working example at the [myfonts.com's advanced search](https://www.myfonts.com/search/serif/)

[image: myfonts]

Comment: For me this looks like i would add a variant on a variant instead of adding it to the same layer.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your explanation but placing the "add variant" next to the variant name itself seems more confusing. That's why on my design the "add variant" is only placed on top altogether with the title.

Comment: What's the step when the user wants to delete a variant?

Comment: On my overall design, I put the "delete" button on the bottom of the product information. It will automatically delete the variant then. @Danielillo